# Positioning an <hr> or Material UI Divider From Bottom of Webpage

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using react and material ui to create the view for a webpage. The problem I am encountering is that I am unsure how to place the divider close to the bottom of the webpage and stick a logo there.

I have in React.js in my jsx file a react functional component that has in it a material UI drawer hugging the left pane of my browser inside I have put my divider as such:

```
<Drawer styles={{}}>
    ... (MaterialUI ListItem Components) ... and then

    <Divider />
</Drawer>
```

I was thinking of either using style property such as bottom: to fix this, but when I use position and bottom css properties together the position property doesn't do anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have made a codepen link for this. Since the wrapper is a flex-container(by `display: flex`), this trick is to use `flex: 1 0 auto` for `Example 3`. It will make that div's height enough to push the rest element downward. Check [here](https://codepen.io/fyrankeeevitse/pen/ZEBJJLm)

Comment: Thank you for the codepen! But I took a look and I am not sure if it is just codepen that is causing the issue, but the vertical space isnt being created

Comment: @devdev just testing other thing before. Now should be ok. Click the link again.